# inheriting constructors doesn't allow array-like initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, constructor

Is this a g++ bug?

```
#include <array>

struct inherit : std::array<int , 3>{
    using std::array<int , 3>::array;
};

std::array<int, 3> ok1 = {1,2,3};
inherit ok2;
inherit bad = {1,2,3};
```

Instantiating `bad`, I get `error: could not convert ‘{1, 2, 3}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘inherit’`. It looks absolutely correct to me.

Comment: `std::array` has an implicitly declared constructor. So construction uses aggregate initialization. Aggregates cannot have base classes, so `inherit` is not an aggregate and therefore cannot use aggregate initialization.

Comment: There is a link talking about aggregate initialization. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::array` is an aggregate. It has no user defined constructors.

From the C++ Standard

> 1 An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

class inherit is not an aggregate because it has a base class. So it may not use the brace initialization (except an empty initializer list). You should explicitly define constructors for class inherit if you want to initialize it with a non empty initializer list,